# How to scroll down a scrollview while scrolling from another scrollview in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollbar

I have two *scrollview* and I want to scroll any of the scrollview such that another scrollview also scroll down. Is is possible in android? If yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ScrollView sv1 = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview1);
ScrollView sv2 = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview2);

sv1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {
        sv2.scrollTo(sv1.getScrollX(), sv1.getScrollY());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. :) Works Perfectly. :)